# Android: show keyboard on PIN EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I'm very new to android programming and working on an existing app. The app has a PIN entry with 4 digits. The problem I face, is that the keyboard is not showing every time when the PIN entry mask shows up, sometimes the keyboard is showing and somethimes not. In the app are 4 cases, when the PIN entry is showed: after login, when the app is opened and a user is logged in, to enter the profile settings and to change the PIN. The behaviour is really strange, it isn't like the keyboard gets toggled, so one time it shows and the next time it doesn't, it appears random.

This is the part which should show the keyboard:

```
public void showSoftInput() {
    if (mEditText != null) {
        mEditText.requestFocus();
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.showSoftInput(mEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is give a focus to your pin edittext, something else is taking the focus, may be because of that keyboard is not coming up.

try `requestfocus` to give focus to your PIN edittext

Programatically

```
edittext.requestFocus();
```

in the xml if you want

```
<EditText...>
    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

Comment: The edittext is formed in the PINinput.java file, in the xml file is just one pattern of the 4, they are set togheter in the code. It's dynamically, that you can change the amount of required digits to 5, for example, and in the loop the right amount of patterns gets merged togheter.

Comment: so what, whenever your activity opens, call requestfocus on that particular edittext in the oncreate of that activity.